# ROT13 in Java doesn´t want to work properly

Tags: java, eclipse, rot13

At some point I have trouble programming ROT13 in Java. So the User shall write whatever he wants and the programm should rewrite it in ROT13. So here´s my programm until now:

```
import java.io.*;


public class rot13

{

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));// Buffered Reader reads the number inputed 

    String key [] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    String keyA [] = {"N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"};
    String letter;

    System.out.println("Enter a phrase:");
    String phrase = myInput.readLine();
    int y = 0, i = 0;
    while ( y <= phrase.length()){

        letter = Character.toString(phrase.charAt(y));

        while(i <= y){

            if (letter != key[i]){
                keyA [i] = keyA[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(keyA [i]);
        y++;
        } 
    }
}
```

The problem is the following:
It only does go for a few letters, but stops working after like 3 lines or rather after 3 latters and puts up errors which are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at rot13.main(rot13.java:19)
```

I´ve tried different words, but it keeps printing out the same problem. Does anyone knows how to fix it or at least a way to do it more proberly?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `keyA[i] = keyA[i]` doesn't do anything useful. Your while loop should probably loop `for (i=0 ; i < key.Length ; +i)` and then break out once you find the character you want (not very efficient, but it'll work).  Be sure to detect and handle the case where the letter is not in the key array.  What if they type a space?

Comment: So I should delete keyA[i] = keyA[i] and replace it with for(i=0; i<key.lenght;i++) , right?

Comment: No.  Replace the whole `while` loop with a `for` loop.  Inside that loop, if letter == key[i], print it and keep track of a flag to know whether or not you found the letter, and then `break` out of the loop.  After the loop, check your flag and if the letter was not found, just print it.  That way, non-alphabetic characters will print as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why it doesn't work

```
import java.io.*;


public class rot13

{

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));// Buffered Reader reads the number inputed 

String key [] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
String keyA [] = {"N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"};
String letter;

System.out.println("Enter a phrase:");
String phrase = myInput.readLine();
int y = 0, i = 0;
while ( y <= phrase.length()){

    letter = Character.toString(phrase.charAt(y));
    //Each time you go throught the first loop, you are comparing your actual position in the string and i
    //But as you don't reset i back to 0, you only try to compare your previous index and your actual index : if y == 3, so i takes only the values 2 and 3
    //Moreover, when y > 26, you try to access the key array outside of its bounds 
    while(i <= y){
        // letter is a string so you should be using equals
        if (letter != key[i]){
            // You are putting the value at the i index in the i index, so you do basically nothing with this line
            keyA [i] = keyA[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(keyA [i]);
    y++;
    } 
}
```

}

#### Alternative

Here's a solution you can use :

```
import java.io.*;


public class rot13 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));// Buffered Reader reads the number inputed
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase:");
    String input = myInput.readLine();

    //We loop through every char in the string
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        //We check if the character is a letter, so we don't add the offset to special characters like space or dot
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
            //Here we get the lower case version of the char and remove it 97, which is the ascii value of 'a'
            //With this, we are mapping letters from a to z to numbers from 0 to 25
            char lowerChar = (char) (Character.toLowerCase(c) - 97);
            //We add the offset of 13
            lowerChar += 13;
            //We then use the modulo to move numbers higher than 15 back to the beginning
            lowerChar %= 26;
            //We finally come back to the ascii value of our lower case char
            lowerChar += 97;
            System.out.print(Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toUpperCase(lowerChar) : lowerChar);
        } else {
            //If it's not a letter, we just print the char
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    //We don't forget to close our BuffererReader
    myInput.close();
}
}
```

This is a described version but you can shorten it by doing all the char operations on one line

Comment: Nice.  Very complete and efficient solution.